# date and time can't be changed windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, date

I need to change my date to something wrong for some reasons. I get no errors and there are no other problems and I can see the change in the left-bottom corner, but after just after a few seconds or so, it goes back to the previous state just like nothing have happened.

P.S.: "set date automatically" in setting is off.

Comment: Hi Faridzs, welcome to Super User. By 'set date automatically', do you mean the `Synchronize with an Internet time server` checkbox?

Comment: well, I simply restarted the computer and the problem seems to be solved for now. anyway , where is that checkbox? 'cause I've had that problem before and restarting haven't helped then.

Comment: I have posted the steps to get to `Internet time` settings as an answer for ease of formatting. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Windows may be synching with a time server (aka `ntp`). You can turn this off in time preferences by going through the following:

**1)** Right click on clock in system tray -> Adjust date/time:

[image: Adjust date/time]

gives

[image: Windows time settings]

**2)** Go to `Internet time` tab:

[image: Internet time tab]

and click on `Change Settings` to give

[image: internet time settings]

where you can disable (or enable) synchronisation.

Comment: i checked that part and i saw that it wasn't synchronizing. just to see what will happen i turned it on and now when i change the date it doesn't go back that is another problem :) . nevermind ! my computer is ok at the moment. thank you for your help.

Comment: @Faridzs glad it is working okay for now anyway :)